# How to pass a php variable to a twig template

Tags: php, templates, twig, templating

I am using twig for the first time and I want to pass a variable to the template, So How I can pass a new template variable?
I want to add something like :

```
{{ Total_project }}
```

This variable is a return for a function that count the projects and return the total:

```
public function total_projects(){
        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT project_id as total_project FROM Projects")) {
            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            }
    }
```

What shall I do exactly?

Comment: You pass the variables when you render the template. See [the docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#rendering-templates) for more info.

Comment: The template is already rendered!

Comment: Call the function _before_ render, and pass the result into twig per the docs @rickdenhaan pointed you at. Also, your function doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0):

Rendering with template :

```
    public function total_projects(){
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT project_id as total_project FROM Projects")) {
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_project = $result['total_project'];
    }

    return $this->render('index.html.twig', array(
        'Total_project' => $total_project
    ));
}
```